# Pandas melt but for dates inside a range

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with both "From" and "Until" dates for each line, like the example below:

```
+------------+------------+---------+-----------+-----+-----+
|    From    |   Until    | Product | BaseValue | Tax | Int |
+------------+------------+---------+-----------+-----+-----+
| 01/01/2020 | 01/02/2020 | A       |       200 |  50 |  10 |
| 01/01/2020 | 01/02/2020 | B       |       500 |  15 |   5 |
| 01/01/2020 | 01/02/2020 | C       |       150 |  10 |   2 |
+------------+------------+---------+-----------+-----+-----+
```

However, I need to "melt" the dates from each line, creating one new line for each date that fits between "From" and "Until".
For example, expected result:

```
+------------+---------+-----------+-----+-----+
|    Date    | Product | BaseValue | Tax | Int |
+------------+---------+-----------+-----+-----+
| 01/01/2020 | A       | 200       | 50  | 10  |
| 02/01/2020 | A       | 200       | 50  | 10  |
| 03/01/2020 | A       | 200       | 50  | 10  |
| ...        | ...     | ...       | ... | ... |
| 01/02/2020 | A       | 200       | 50  | 10  |
| 01/01/2020 | B       | 500       | 15  | 5   |
| 02/01/2020 | B       | 500       | 15  | 5   |
| 03/01/2020 | B       | 500       | 15  | 5   |
| ...        | ...     | ...       | ... | ... |
| 01/02/2020 | B       | 500       | 15  | 5   |
+------------+---------+-----------+-----+-----+
```

What's the sharpest way of doing this?

Comment: What is your way in comparison? Maybe you have already the "sharpest way" (whatever that means).

Comment: My way is awful... It would be iterating between "01/01/2020" and whatever end-date, and for each iterated date, i would also iterate by product, and i search the original df for a line that would fit, then append to another dataframe.
However, that kind of iteration in a big dataframe as mine is just melting the cpu...
Also, it's not pythonic at all.

Comment: Ewww. Sounds like my way. Can you add this to the question so that nobody comes up with the idea to post this as an answer?

Comment: I could also create a function to run on "apply(lambda x; ..., axis = 1)", meaning that would iterate over each df line, and that function would pick the "From" and "Until" date, and replicate each line for each between those dates.
That would be smoother but i don't know if i can append to a df from inside of a lambda function.
Anyway, i think there might be a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that *From* and *Until* columns are of *datetime* type.

Define the following function to convert each row into a DataFrame with
this row "proliferated" for each date:

```
def proc(row):
    dct = row.loc['Product':'Int'].to_dict()
    return pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range(row.From, row.Until)}).assign(**dct)
```

Then apply it to each row and concatenate the result:

```
result = pd.concat(df.apply(proc, axis=1).tolist(), ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Beatiful answer! It's been a while since i learned this much from a single answer.
I like how you did apply and then tolist() to create multiple dataframes. I didn't even know that was possible. Thank you. This answer deserves a lot more visibility